# Monitoring Terminal Server

Tags: windows-server-2003

What is the best way to monitor a terminal server session that is being shadowed? I believe I have an admin shadowing one of our users and talking in notepad. Does anyone have any suggestions on the easiest way to find this?

Comment: What do you mean by monitor?  Do you want to know who is shadowing who, what they are saying, or what?

Comment: Do you want to know when a shadow session occurs on 2003 terminal services or when a shadow session occurs on remote administration mode?

Comment: I was wondering if 2 people can shadow 1 session. I'm thinking my best bet may be to install a keylogger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attempt to shadow a terminal session will result in a prompt requesting a shadow session to be allowed.  If the user has not been prompted to allow the shadow then most likely it's not happening.

That is not to say, however, that activities similar to what you are describing can't be done via other methods.

**EDIT:**
As Tom pointed out, the aforementioned prompt can be disabled in the Terminal Services Configuration.  Hopefully this isn't the case for you.

You could also ask another admin (if you have one) to look at the sessions on the terminal server, or look yourself if you have the permissions, and see if the admin in question is logged in.  Terminal services manager will show the state of a session that is shadowing another as "RemoteControl".

You could look for an rdpclip.exe process running on the server under the context of the admin's user ID.  That'll indicate that the admin has a terminal session, but not necessarily whether or not they're shadowing anyone.

Comment: Remote control can be configured to not require the users permission, at the GPO or RDP level.

Answer (score 0):

The "prompt" referred to above can be disabled in Terminal Service Manager. FYI.

Comment: That's a good point, I had forgotten about that.  (You should leave a comment on my answer, though, instead of posting a new answer.)

Comment: Ah, still learning the site, thanks. Good luck!

Tom